# Бесплатный сервер от гугла

Tags: google-cloud

решил найти себе сервер для теста и учебы, конечно мог остановиться на локальном сервере, но мне нужно связь с телефона, в интернете нашел много таких сервисов, все которые я попробовал слишком медленные, т.е. загрузка из них очень долгая, но тут вдруг нашел что гугл дает бесплатно свои сервера, у них то скорость не будет ниже чем у других это точно, что они дают, 300 долларов на год (кредита на свои сервисы, но я так и не понял нужно ли их потом возвращать) и 30 ГБ   памяти на один виртуальный ЖД, да еще и после года, 300 если не использовались то списываються, но сервер дальше будет стоять, у меня накопилось много вопросов, основные это:

1) Что за кредит, по скольку я привязываю свою карту банка, нужно ли будет потом что-то возвращать?

2) Нужно ли вообще за этот бесплатный сервис на котором 30 ГБ мне дадут чуть ли не пожизнено?

3) Что самому гуглу с этого?

4) Есть ли какие-то подводные камни в этом?

Comment: Не скажу про GC. Мой друг взял себе Малинку (Raspberry Pi), настроил её под сервер и использует как хочет. Ценник на данное "чудо-техники" не такой уж и большой.

Answer (score 3):

> Нужно ли вообще за этот бесплатный сервис на котором 30 ГБ мне дадут чуть ли не пожизнено?

С [Always Free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits) все не так уж и просто и нужно считать. Например, для Compute Engine они дают 30Гб HDD только в трех регионах, но вот трафика бесплатного входит только 1 Gb. И то же самое с Cloud Storage.

> Что самому гуглу с этого?

Google дает 300 долларов, чтобы вы попробовали их облачные сервисы. Все сервисы доступные в Google Cloud Platform, а не только серваки. Есть вероятность (я думаю достаточно хорошо посчитанная), что каждый n'ый получивший эти самые 300 долларов потом перенесет свою инфраструктуру в GCP и принесет в результате прибыль компании.

Если вам нужно поразбираться и поиграться с тем, что предлагает Google в облаке - то этого вам хватит. Если вам интересно, сможете ли вы свое решение перенести в Google'овское облако и прицениться сколько вам будет потом стоить содержать какие-то сервисы в GCP - то этого вам хватит.

Если вы думаете, что это просто возможность получить что-то на халяву - вам не туда. В таких компаниях сидят достаточно ушлые ребята чтобы и подать красиво и денег не потерять.

Answer (score 2):

Бесплатная услуга, для которой надо привязывать (!) кредитку, уже наводит на мысли. Дело ваше, но я бы, пожалуй, не рискнул.

Набираете в том же самом гугле "cheap vps hosting" либо "cheap cloud hosting", и сразу вываливается куча предложений начиная от 3 долларов в месяц. Наверное, можно найти и немного дешевле, я посмотрел только несколько первых предложений. Да, там нужно платить, но деньги небольшие, привязку карточки не требуют, и в любой момент можно отказаться. А если платить через пейпал, к примеру, то точно не будет никаких сюрпризов с неожиданными списаниями с карты.

Еще момент, который стоит учитывать: cloud server - это не сервер в обычном понимании, скорее это некая сетевая служба. Тогда как VPS - это обычный Windows или Linux сервер, на котором вы можете запускать любую программу на любых портах. Оборотной стороной является некоторая проблема с надежностью - в отличие от облака, если сервер упал, значит его в сети нет. Ну и для администрирования своего сервера все же нужна некоторая базовая квалификация. В общем, смотрите по своей задаче устроит ли вас облачный сервис, серверные возможности там очень ограничены.

Comment: вот я тоже бы не рискнул, не спросив бы, да я понимаю что cloud server это не совсем сервер, даже если будет простая серверная винда я там бы поставил, это не проблема, держать не где пока.

Comment: @kitsoRik, не вполне понял ваш комментарий... что вам "негде держать"? VPS не надо нигде держать, это удаленный сервер в датацентре, вы его никогда в глаза не увидите. Виртуальный сервер, если точнее.

Comment: я знаю, говорил об ситуации на то время, когда еще нет удаленного сервера

Comment: @kitsoRik, от момента заказа сервера до получения письма "ваш IP такой-то, пароль рута такой-то" - это буквально два-три часа. Даже у самых тормозных хостеров все равно меньше суток.

Comment: вопрос вообще был про то не рисковано ли это, давать данные от карты фиг знает куда, был бы это не гугл, давно бы уже забыл и пошел дальше, но эти ребята по-моему не такие, что бы снимать деньги без предупреждения (хотя бы великим текстом на страницу, а не скрывать где-то снизу), есть ли так что-то такое? И да, облачный сервис меня устроит.

Comment: @kitsoRik, конечно рискованно. Это по определению рискованно давать кому-то доступ к своей карте с разрешением снимать оттуда деньги. Да, гугл не станет сознательно воровать, но они вполне могут начать снимать по ошибке, и вы будете названивать им в поддержку и доказывать что это ошибка. Никогда не пробовали что-то доказать в своем банке? Очень помогает понять как сложно найти правду в большой заформализованной конторе, которой по большому счету плевать на отдельного мелкого клиента. Но это, конечно, всего лишь мое личное мнение, никаких конкретных проступков за гуглом не знаю.

Comment: Я привязал кредитку к azure, спустя несколько месяцев минус 9 килорублей. весьма обидно. Потестил, блин. Так что зарплатную ни в коем случае не привязывайте)))